# Set Link For Pdf Image Annotation In pdf-lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I have a PDF file and I am trying to add an image and a rectangle, with a link attached to it, over the image.

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib

```
 const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(await pdf.getData());

    const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()

    const page = pages[index]

    const pngImage = await pdfDoc.embedPng(pngImageBytes)
    
    const pngDims = pngImage.scale(0.5)
    
    // Draw the PNG image near the lower right corner of the JPG image

    //   x: page.getWidth() / 2 - pngDims.width / 2 + 75,
    //   y: page.getHeight() / 2 - pngDims.height,
    page.drawImage(pngImage, {
        x:coordinations.x - pngDims.width / 2,
        y:coordinations.y - pngDims.height / 2,
        width: pngDims.width,
        height: pngDims.height,
    })

    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()
```

The image is created, but I can't find a way to create a rectangle with a link to be layered over the image so that people can click on the image and open the link.

Comment: https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfbutton 
I Found This Section In Pdf Lib Documentation But I Cant Find A Way To Attach The LInk ....

Comment: i tried https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfbutton

but it is annotation type 20 with subtype of widget 

but i want annotation type 2 with subtype of link and no background color so people can see image and click on annotation .....

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { PDFDocument, PDFName } = require('pdf-lib');

const PAGE_WIDTH = 500;
const PAGE_HEIGHT = 750;

const createPageLinkAnnotation = (pdfDoc, pageRef) => ////CREATE HYPERLINK METHOD
  pdfDoc.context.register(
    pdfDoc.context.obj({
      Type: 'Annot',
      Subtype: 'Link',
      /* Bounds of the link on the page */
      Rect: [
        145, // lower left x coord
        PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 - 10, // lower left y coord
        358, // upper right x coord
        PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 + 25, // upper right y coord
      ],
      /* Give the link a 2-unit-wide border, with sharp corners */
      Border: [0, 0, 2],
      /* Make the border color blue: rgb(0, 0, 1) */
      C: [0, 0, 1],
      /* Page to be visited when the link is clicked */
      Dest: [pageRef, 'XYZ', null, null, null],
    }),
);






(async () => { ////CREATE PDF WITH 3 PAGES ==> EACH HAS HYPERLINK TO NEXT PAGE
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();

  const page1 = pdfDoc.addPage([PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT]);
  const page2 = pdfDoc.addPage([PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT]);
  const page3 = pdfDoc.addPage([PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT]);

  page1.drawText('PAGE 1', { size: 50, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 100 });
  page1.drawText('Go to Page 2', { size: 24, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 });

  page2.drawText('PAGE 2', { size: 50, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 100 });
  page2.drawText('Go to Page 3', { size: 24, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 });

  page3.drawText('PAGE 3', { size: 50, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 100 });
  page3.drawText('Go to Page 1', { size: 24, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 });

  const link1 = createPageLinkAnnotation(pdfDoc, page1.ref);
  const link2 = createPageLinkAnnotation(pdfDoc, page2.ref);
  const link3 = createPageLinkAnnotation(pdfDoc, page3.ref);

  page1.node.set(PDFName.of('Annots'), pdfDoc.context.obj([link2]));
  page2.node.set(PDFName.of('Annots'), pdfDoc.context.obj([link3]));
  page3.node.set(PDFName.of('Annots'), pdfDoc.context.obj([link1]));

  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  fs.writeFileSync('./out.pdf', pdfBytes);
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! While this code may solve the OP's issue, code only responses are frowned upon on SO. Consider editing to highlight essential elements of your solution & explain how it solves the OP's issue, or differs from their attempt. Links to documentation or other sources can also be great supplements. Quality answers are more likely to be upvoted over time as users learn something to apply to their own coding issues and prevent issues in the first place. Good answers keep SO quality high, helps spread knowledge, and prevents "Haz me the code" posts. Looking forward to your insights.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const PDFDocument  = PDFLib.PDFDocument
const PDFName  = PDFLib.PDFName

PDFLib.PDFPage.prototype.addLink = function(refPage,option){ 
  const link = this.doc.context.register(
    this.doc.context.obj({
      Type: 'Annot',
      Subtype: 'Link',
      /* Bounds of the link on the page */
      Rect: [
        option.x + option.w, // lower left x coord
        PAGE_HEIGHT  -option.y , // lower left y coord
        option.x, // upper right x coord
        PAGE_HEIGHT -option.h  , // upper right y coord
      ],
      /* Give the link a 2-unit-wide border, with sharp corners */
      Border: [5, 5, 5],
      /* Make the border color blue: rgb(255, 255, 1) */
      C: [2, 2, 1],
      /* Page to be visited when the link is clicked */
      Dest: [refPage.ref, 'XYZ', null, null, null],
    }),
  ); 
  this.node.set(PDFName.of('Annots'), this.doc.context.obj([link]));
  return this
} 

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create();

const page1 = pdfDoc.addPage([PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT]);
const page2 = pdfDoc.addPage([PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT]);
const page3 = pdfDoc.addPage([PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT]);

page1.drawText('PAGE 1', { size: 50, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 100 });
page1.drawText('Go to Page 2', { size: 24, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 });

page2.drawText('PAGE 2', { size: 50, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 100 });
page2.drawText('Go to Page 3', { size: 24, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 });

page3.drawText('PAGE 3', { size: 50, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 100 });
page3.drawText('Go to Page 1', { size: 24, x: 175, y: PAGE_HEIGHT - 200 });

const option = {x:0,y:0,w:200,h:50}
page1.addLink(page2,option)
page2.addLink(page3,option)
page3.addLink(page1,option)
```